# Arrays.sort Issue?

Tags: arrays, sorting, junit

I want to sort card objects that I made. I made an array to help sort the cards in order, however my Arrays.sort (cards) fails my junit test. Is there an issue with my testSort() method? My setUp() test passes so it isn't that.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.Arrays;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class CardTest {

   private Card twoOfClubs; 
   private Card fourOfDiamonds;
   private Card sixOfHearts;
   private Card tenOfSpades;

   @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

       twoOfClubs = new Card(Rank.TWO, Suit.CLUBS);
       fourOfDiamonds = new Card(Rank.FOUR, Suit.DIAMONDS);
       sixOfHearts = new Card(Rank.SIX, Suit.HEARTS);
       tenOfSpades = new Card(Rank.TEN, Suit.SPADES);
   }

    @Test
    public void testSort() {

       Card[] cards = new Card[4];

       Arrays.sort(cards);

       assertEquals(twoOfClubs, cards[0]);
       assertEquals(fourOfDiamonds, cards[1]);
       assertEquals(sixOfHearts, cards[2]);
       assertEquals(tenOfSpades, cards[3])

   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never place the cards into the cards array. maybe change your `@Before` to something like this:

```
private Card[] cards;
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       cards = new Card[4];
       twoOfClubs = new Card(Rank.TWO, Suit.CLUBS);
       fourOfDiamonds = new Card(Rank.FOUR, Suit.DIAMONDS);
       sixOfHearts = new Card(Rank.SIX, Suit.HEARTS);
       tenOfSpades = new Card(Rank.TEN, Suit.SPADES);
       cards = {tenOfSpades,fourOfDiamonds,twoOfClubs,sixOfHearts}
   }
```

Basically you need to add the cards to your test array some how.

Your test would then just look like:

```
 @Test
    public void testSort() {

       Arrays.sort(cards);

       assertEquals(twoOfClubs, cards[0]);
       assertEquals(fourOfDiamonds, cards[1]);
       assertEquals(sixOfHearts, cards[2]);
       assertEquals(tenOfSpades, cards[3])

   }
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. But one last thing. How can I call cards from setUp() to testSort()? It says that cards cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @dj5 ah, I missed that, You may have to declare cards outside of the functions. This way it's available to both functions.

Comment: Oh... That went over my head haha. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

And just for the record, you can write down your test in a much easier to read way:

```
Club[] expectedCards = { new Club ... };

Club[] sortedCards = ... running your "code to sort"

assertThat(sortedCards, is(expectedCards))
```